# Does Lambdatest Playwright support playwright bundled browsers

Tags: testing, automated-tests, playwright, lambdatest

I am new to Lambdatest Playwright.
As seen in Lambdatest capability generator https://www.lambdatest.com/capabilities-generator/, chrome browsers are supported. I want to know if those browsers will be bundled browsers provided by Playwright or not ?

Comment: This seems more like a question for Lambdatest support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use both bundled as well as non-bundled browsers on Lambdatest for Playwright.
In order to use non-bundled browsers, use the [capability generator](https://www.lambdatest.com/capabilities-generator/) to get the capability names to choose browser name and browser version.

And, as mentioned in [Lambdatest Playwright documentation](https://www.lambdatest.com/support/docs/test-execution-setup/#choosing-browser-and-os) , in order to use bundled browser, you can pass `pw-chromium, pw-webkit, or pw-firefox` as `browserName`.